# Select distinct values from a table and add 'count' column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Generally, our application for statistics records searches by IP. That means - three IPs and one query, 3 entries in a database.

We need to show statistic of those searches, but imagine that we have:

```
query | count | ip

where    2     127.0.0.1
where    1     127.0.0.2
where    4     127.0.0.3
who      4     127.0.2.1
```

I need, in my rails application, to sort these 'where' as one query. So, if I write Search.order('count DESC'), I need to get results like

```
query | count
where     7
who       4
```

Does anyone have solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select query, sum(count) as SumCount from table group by query
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will get you started

```
select query, sum(count) thecount
from etc
```